# Adding two integers together using only 1's

Tags: java

http://puu.sh/8ekfm.png
Zonko's government (The Kingdom of Zumbania) decided to ban directly adding numbers greater than 1 to other numbers. Zonko decided to create his own addition method (for positive integers) to circumvent the ban. Can you help finish his code?

To get the sum of a and b, Zonko starts by setting a variable sum equal to a. He then repeatedly adds 1 to sum until it reaches a+b. 1 is added every iteration of the loop until its been added the right number of times. What is the correct condition in the loop so it stops at the right time?

```
public int add(int a, int b){
int sum = a;
for(int i=1; LOOP-CONDITION; i=i+1){
  sum = sum + 1;    //this will add 1 to sum every iteration
}
return sum;
}
```

Can someone explain this and tell me how they got the answer?

Comment: You start in the loop by creating a new variable and setting it equal to `a`. Now you want to add `b` to it, but you can only add it `1` at at ime. So how many `1's` do you add? Well, just loop over b 1 at a time and add 1 each time, until you reach `b`.

Comment: Better title, please.

Comment: You need to change you `LOOP-CONDITION` to well your "loop condition".

Comment: What a stupid challenge. Not in the sense that you are unintelligent but the whole approach is ridiculous. You could easily change that whole method to `return one += two;`. If you wanted it greater than 1, you can use a ternary: `return one > 1 ? one += two : one;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java idiomatic for loops to perform an action a certain number of times are:

```
for(int i=1; i <= [numTimes]; i=i+1){
```

and

```
for(int i=0; i < [numTimes]; i=i+1){
```

The former has the correct starting condition, so your loop condition would be: `i <= b`.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is in the words :

> Zonko's government (The Kingdom of Zumbania) decided to ban directly
>   adding numbers greater than 1 to other numbers.

This means `a` cannot be added to `b` directly when `b` is greater than 1.

Assume you want to add `a = 5` and `b = 3`. You can get the answer by adding `1` to `5` three times.

```
a = 5;  
loop(b times){
  a = a + 1;
}
```

Here is how the loop will go:

```
a = 5;
loop starts
  a = 5 + 1;
  a = 6 + 1; // we made it 6 in previous step
  a = 7 + 1; 
loop ends
```